# Project location must be empty when creating a new project?

Tags: aptana

Good afternoon.

I've tried to find an answer to this question but can't seem to find one.

I'm using a study guide to teach myself HTML5 and CSS3. This study guide comes with some material to use for exercises.

The first step is for me to create a new project using the provided material but every time I try I am told that the folder I have set for the project is not empty.

The steps I am told to use are as follows:

1. File > New > Web Project
2. Set Template
3. Next
4. Project Name
5. Uncheck "Use default Location"
6. Browse to the folder containing the provided material for the exercises.

When I complete step #6 I receive the following message:

```
 Folder 'c:\target' is not empty
```

At this point I am unable to click either the Next or the Finish button.

Am I missing something? There are approximately 20 chapters worth of exercises with each exercise consisting of multiple files. Do I really have to import them individually?

I am using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603 in Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of choosing `File > New > Project`, use `File > Import > Existing Folder as New Project`.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. Do you know if it's possible to do what the book was telling me of do I have to use the process you gave above?

IF it's the former then that does not bode well for the accuracy of the book I fear.

Comment: AFAIK when you want to use an existing folder like your demo, you use this method, when you want to start from scratch you choose New. Doesn't seem like a workaround to me, and I wouldn't worry too much about the accuracy of the book. Open source software changes, you have to be a little flexible. You'll learn more from the book being a little wrong and you having to think about what you are trying to do anyway. Mark as answer?

Comment: Hi Sarah. As it turns out it seems that this is a change from Aptana 3.0. According to the author of the book I'm using in 3.0 one could use File>New>Web Project to create a new project using existing folders but in the 3.4 build it looks like the process you provided me is the new way of doing things.

No idea if that's accurate as I have never used 3.0 but I just wanted to say thanks.

Comment: Sure. I think I just did it. Please let me know if otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on a Mac with Mountain Lion.  I do not find 'Existing Folder as New Project' under the File > Import menu.  The Import menu item under File just brings up a dialog box asking for a source.

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana Studio 3 I found the 'Existing Folder as New Project' by using import--General-->Existing Folder as New Project.