# AptanaStudio3, Drupal 7.23, and OS X 10.8.5

Tags: directory, aptana

I have installed MAMP with Drupal 7.23 with no issues 
I am trying to use "Aptana" for the first time. I am pointing to my new project ( unchecked the default location) but Aptana refuses with error below

Folder '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/'projectname' is not empty.

Any pointers is much appreciated. I am complete newbie.

I strolled the internet but to no avail. I even bought a book but still no dice :)

Please help...

Many thanks

zongo saiba

Comment: Have you asked for help on Aptana's support forum?

Comment: Is the folder it mentions not empty? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674265/project-location-must-be-empty-when-creating-a-new-project/16674359#16674359